# Unknown partition table type error from u-boot running on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: boot, partitioning, raspberry-pi, sd-card

I've been trying to run the Linux on my **Raspberry Pi 4** board. But, I couldn't even achieve running the ***u-boot*** properly. The board launches up without any problem and starts running the ***u-boot***. The ***u-boot*** then tries to read the contents of the SD card but it cannot. This is how the terminal screen looks like:

```
U-Boot 2021.01 (Aug 07 2021 - 16:54:46 +0300)
DRAM:  7.9 GiB
RPI 4 Model B
MMC:   mmcnr@7e300000: 1, emmc2@7e340000: 0
Loading Environment from FAT... ** No partition table - mmc 0 **
... (Some unrelated info here)
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
** No partition table - mmc 0 **
Card did not respond to voltage select! : -110
```

I believe that the partitioning of my SD card has no problem as I've followed the SD Card preparation tutorials carefully. Here you can see the output produced by `fdisk` tool below.

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 119,9 GiB, 127865454592 bytes, 249737216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xbb50dfe5

Device         Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1 *     2048 249737215 249735168 119,1G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Whenever I call the `mmc part` or `fatls mmc 0:1` commands, I see the following error prompts.

```
U-Boot> mmc part
## Unknown partition table type 0
U-Boot> fatls mmc 0:1
** No partition table - mmc 0 **
```

What do you think that I'm doing wrong? How should I continue searching for a solution?

By the way, the ***u-boot*** that I'm using was compiled using `aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu-gcc` and it had been cloned from the mainline [repo](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot).

The first 512 bytes of the SD card are as follows.

```
0000000 58eb 6d90 666b 2e73 6166 0074 4002 0040
0000010 0002 0000 f800 0000 0010 0004 0800 0000
0000020 a800 0ee2 7740 0000 0000 0000 0002 0000
0000030 0001 0006 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000040 0180 9829 1a87 5662 4c4f 4d55 5f45 414e
0000050 454d 4146 3354 2032 2020 1f0e 77be ac7c
0000060 c022 0b74 b456 bb0e 0007 10cd eb5e 32f0
0000070 cde4 cd16 eb19 54fe 6968 2073 7369 6e20
0000080 746f 6120 6220 6f6f 6174 6c62 2065 6964
0000090 6b73 202e 5020 656c 7361 2065 6e69 6573
00000a0 7472 6120 6220 6f6f 6174 6c62 2065 6c66
00000b0 706f 7970 6120 646e 0a0d 7270 7365 2073
00000c0 6e61 2079 656b 2079 6f74 7420 7972 6120
00000d0 6167 6e69 2e20 2e2e 0d20 000a 0000 0000
00000e0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
00001f0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 aa55
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue as you. Did you ever figure out what was the reason?

Comment: @KarimAly Unfortunately, no.

Comment: I was using u-boot tag 'v2021.01' but when I moved to a newer tag (tag 'v2021.10' to be specific), I can now read files from a FAT partition with no issues. A whole day spinning my head for this issue :D. Next time, first thing to try is to just try a different release.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a problem:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 *     2048 249737215 249735168 119,1G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

As per [U-Boot Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_U-Boot#Compatible_file_systems) u-boot supports only FAT, not FAT32. [U-Boot manual](http://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/Manual) doesn't mention it either, just plain old FAT.